# user has many images using paperclip in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphism, paperclip

i have been using `paperclip` with model as `user has_many :images` and `image belongs_to:user`.now i want to get the **polymorphism** working for the image model such that user,post has many images and `image belongs to imageable polymorphic=>true`.i am working on it but i am not confident as im not clear with the concepts of paperclip as such.Now these are the changes that i did but what further changes do i need to make to get an association as `user has many images` and `images belongs to imageable ,polymorphic =>true.`Below is what i have done but not getting any result.any help will be appreciated...**.I JUST NEED polymorphism of image such as user has many images,post has many images.....etc where image belongs to imageable,:polymorphic =true.**

**image.rb**

```
belongs_to :imageable,:polymorphic=>true
has_attached_file :avatar, :url  => "/assets/images/#{imageable_type}/#{imageable_id}/:style/:basename.:extension",
             :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/images/#{imageable_type}/#{imageable_id}/:style/:basename.:extension", :default_url => 'dashboard/default_avatar.jp
```

g'

**user.rb**

```
has many:images ,:as=>imageable,:dependent=>destroy
```

**migration file to images**

```
class CreateImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :images do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :site
      t.string :image_file_name, :null => true
      t.string :image_content_type, :null => true
      t.integer :image_file_size, :null => true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**migration for user.rb**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :username
      t.string :mobile_number
      t.string :email
      t.references :image
      t.timestamps
    end
```

**my view form where i will allow user to upload image or edit image**

***profile.html.erb.....using remotipart gem***

```
<%= form_for(@user,:url=>'add_image_to_user_path',:html => {:multipart => true},:remote=>true) do |f |%>
<%= f.file_field :images, :multiple => true %>
<%= f.submit "Add image" %>
<%end%>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
    ##now how i should update the users image who has already logged in
    ##i tried @user.update_attribute(params[:user]) but i cannot see any update query in the log
 -   ##i can only see --->paperclip saving attachment
    def add_image_to_user
       @user=User.new
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with paperclip, it's all about polymorphic association. Now, polymorphic association is very similar to regular association - the only difference, looking from the point of view of DB schema, is existence of another column in "belonging" model (in your case, it's `imageable_type`), that contains class of associated record. So, firstly, you should remove `t.references :image` from `create_users` migration, as it's unnecessary there. Secondly, you should add your foreign key column and association type column to `create_images` migration. You can do it with single 'directive', like this:

```
t.references :imageable, polymorphic: true
```

and this should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you need a [`has_many :through` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association). This will allow you to keep your `image`, `user` and `post` models all separate

I think your problem is that you're limiting the association of the images to specific objects, which you'd like to assign to either `post` or `user`

---

**Has_Many Through**

In our company, we only make `images belong_to :user` (for authorization purposes). For everything else, we use join models with has_many :through associations, as this allows you to create as many associations as you desire

Here's how we do it:

```
#app/models/image.rb
Class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :image_posts, :class_name => 'ImagePost'
    has_many :posts, :class_name => 'Post', :through => :image_posts

    has_many :user_images, :class_name => 'UserImage'
    has_many :users, :class_name => 'User', :through => :user_images
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_images, :class_name => 'UserImage'
    has_many :images, :class_name => 'Image', :through => :user_images
end

#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :image_posts, :class_name => 'ImagePost'
    has_many :images, :class_name => 'Image', :through => :image_posts
end

#app/models/ImagePost.rb
Class ImagePost < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :image
    belongs_to :post
end

   #app/models/UserImage.rb
   Class UserImage < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :image
        belongs_to :user
   end
```

The join models will look like this in the database:

```
user_images
id | user_id | image_id | extra | attributes | created_at | updated_at

image_posts
id | post_id | image_id | extra | attributes | created_at | updated_at
```

This means you'd use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to assign the `image_id` for either `user` or `post`. Because the join model is handling the association, the image remains untouched. I can post how to do this if you feel it applicable